# C what happens in the compiler when -1 is assigned to an unsigned short or uint16_t?

Tags: c, casting, compilation

So I know in the C standard all constants go through a hierarchy to figure out the type of the constant.

The C standard also talks about modulo arithmetic when assigning a wider signed type to a smaller unsigned type.

My question is when I do:

unsigned short s = -1;

I know s contains 0xFFFF (that is the signed representation of -1 for a short). However, by the standard
isn't -1 an int i.e 0xFFFFFFFF (assuming 32 bit ints) and then truncated by modulo arithmetic to get 0xFFFF when assigned to unsigned short s. I am wondering which line of thought is correct to get that representation ? For instance, unsigned short s = -32769 (does s now have 0x7ffe) based on modulo arithmetic on int representation of -32769 (which is beyond the range of short) 0xffff7ffe.

Does compiler already do this truncation before generating the assembly of copying 0xFFFF into a register ?

Similar question when assigning a uint16 with say 0xFFF3 to a uint8 is this implementation defined or the truncation is defined in the standard ?

Comment: as explained in the duplicate, `-1` is adjusted mod `USHRT_MAX+1` until it is in range for unsigned short.  For the last example `0xFFF3` is adjusted mod `UINT8_MAX+1` until it is in range for uint8.  Also, `-1` is not `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: Isn't -1 (in a system with int as 32 bits) just all ff's over 32 bits ?

Comment: you might be thinking of the representation in memory: on a 2's complement system with 32-bit ints then it would store all-bits-1 in memory. But that has no bearing on C's arithmetic which uses value semantics independent of representation, and also it should not be confused with the C constant `0xFFFFFFFF` which is a large positive number.

Comment: Does the compiler do the mod calculation and then generate the assembly to put the final two bytes in the register ? Or does it put the entire 4 bytes in a register and the mod calculation happens in the assembly generated itself ?

Comment: Most likely the compiler will do it but you could check your generated assembly. The compiler has licence to do whatever it likes so as the actual output of the program remains the same.